# Which regulatory agency (if any) is in charge of investigating civilian rocket anomalies?

Tags: rockets, failure, united-states, regulatory, government

Yesterday [Blue Origin's New Shephard had an anomaly during launch](https://arstechnica.com/science/2022/09/blue-origin-rocket-explodes-on-ascent-but-spacecraft-escape-system-works-well/). Happens around 1:22:58 in this video

The accident happened around 29,000ft and the capsule fired its escape motor before parachuting back to Earth. The rocket itself seems to have been lost.

When Virgin Galactic flew outside its designated flight area [the FAA investigated](https://www.cnbc.com/2021/09/29/faa-clears-virgin-galactic-for-flight-after-mishap-investigation.html), but in that case, Virgin Galactic clearly broke *flight* regulations. What (if any) US government agencies investigate a private rocket mishap?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

FAA again. They license all commercial launches, and are responsible for investigating. The [FAA has officially grounded New Shepard](https://news.yahoo.com/faa-oversee-investigation-failed-blue-200406928.html), pending review. They will also oversee the investigation.

Spaceflight in many ways is managed the same way and same agencies as airflight. If there was an airplane accident then the FAA would similarly oversee the investigation of it. Granted within the FAA there are separate departments, they still manage both.

Comment: "Spaceflight in many ways is managed the same way and same agencies as airflight." – This might be related to the fact that you first need to get through the air before you can reach space.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Or just because there's no other agency with related expertise (NASA isn't a regulatory agency). Maybe if and when spaceflight becomes more routine, investigating accidents could be transferred to the NTSB.

Comment: @Barmar: your "if and when" actually happened last week, see https://space.stackexchange.com/a/60341/6156

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann - Which makes me wonder if it would *still* be an FAA matter if the rocket blew up outside of Earth orbit.

Answer (score 17):

## NTSB and FAA share responsibility

You have great timing! Five days ago, FAA and NTSB signed an agreement on this exact issue. You can read the [full text of the agreement here](https://www.ntsb.gov/legal/gc/Documents/NTSB-FAA-Commercial-Space-MOU.pdf) (PDF) and the [NTSB's press release here](https://www.ntsb.gov/news/press-releases/Pages/nr20220909.aspx). NTSB is now responsible if either of the following conditions apply:

> A fatality or serious injury to any person, regardless of whether the
> person was on board the commercial space launch or reentry vehicle, or
> damage to property not associated with the commercial space launch or
> reentry activities or the launch site, from debris that could
> reasonably be expected to cause death or serious injury.

FAA retains primary responsibility for investigating all other mishaps. The New Shepard anomaly did not cause a loss of life and it did not damage non-spaceflight property, so the FAA is in charge.

*In case you're curious, "mishap" is a formal legal term, and it is defined in [14 CFR 401.7](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/401.7).